# Trying to make a simple chessboard for school

Tags: python, python-3.x

So Ive got this far with my code:

```
rivi = input("Enter dimensions \n")
dimension = int(rivi)


while dimension <= 0: 
    rivi = input("dimension")
    dimension = int(rivi)

else:
    for h in range(dimension):
        for l in range(dimension):
            i = ((h + l + 1) % 2)
            print(i, end=(''))
        print()
```

My only question is how I change the 1s and 0s that come out of the code to something else?

Comment: To *what* else?

Answer (score 0):

```
    i = ((h + l + 1) % 2)
    print(i, end=(''))
```

You are printing 'i', which is set to 0 or 1 by your modulo.

Try to print something else than this?

for example:

```
print(' ,', end=(''))
```

will output

```
 , , , ,
 , , , , 
 , , , ,
```

Answer (score 0):

You are just printing 1's and 0's so you can't change them, I think you are looking for **list**

```
board_dim = int(input('enter dimension: '))

board = [[0]*board_dim for row in range(board_dim)] #initializing list of list aka 2d board # list comprehension

for i in range(board_dim):
    for j in range(board_dim):
        board[i][j] = (i+j + 1) % 2

def print_board():
    for row in board:
        print(row)

print_board()

# update first row first col ie 0,0
board[0][0] = 7

print('\nafter update') 
print_board()


enter dimension: 
[1, 0, 1, 0]
[0, 1, 0, 1]
[1, 0, 1, 0]
[0, 1, 0, 1]

after update
[7, 0, 1, 0]
[0, 1, 0, 1]
[1, 0, 1, 0]
[0, 1, 0, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code, you want 2 types of tokens, for example b for black and w for white, so you could try:

```
else:
    tokens = ['b', 'w']
    for h in range(dimension):
        for l in range(dimension):
            i = tokens[(h + l + 1) % 2]
            print(i, end=(''))
        print()
```

It will output, for example, with 4:

```
wbwb
bwbw
wbwb
bwbw
```

You can change it with other strings you like. Though, I think it is a waste as you are not storing them for later use. You can maybe use an array of lists to represent the board.

Well, good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I have a hard time believing someone who understands the code you provided doesn't know how to change a printed `1` & `0` to something else, but heres a fun answer

```
x = dimension // 2
r = dimension % 2

[print('bl wh '*x + 'bl'*r) if i % 2 else print('wh bl '*x + 'wh'*r) for i in range(dimension)]
```

> ```
> Enter dimensions 
> 9
> wh bl wh bl wh bl wh bl wh
> bl wh bl wh bl wh bl wh bl
> wh bl wh bl wh bl wh bl wh
> bl wh bl wh bl wh bl wh bl
> wh bl wh bl wh bl wh bl wh
> bl wh bl wh bl wh bl wh bl
> wh bl wh bl wh bl wh bl wh
> bl wh bl wh bl wh bl wh bl
> wh bl wh bl wh bl wh bl wh
> ```